# Is it possible to certainly assign one worker to one host in the cluster?

Tags: ray

I want each worker to be allocated to different hosts in the cluster. Such as, I have a cluster with 3 hosts, with IP address 192.168.0.100, 192.168.0.101, 192.168.0.102 respectively. I want to create 3 workers, and assign the task of each work to a different host. Could it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah - you can do so with custom resources. The main idea would be for each node to have a specific custom resource, and then your application actors can be specified to have one of the custom resource. See: https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html#specifying-a-node-s-resource-requirements